# Bot does not see members on server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a function that looks for a person by his server's nickname and use it to find the data in the SQLite database.

```
import discord
import datetime
import sqlite3 as sql
from discord.ext import commands
...
#TOKEN and SQLite database lines
...
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "{", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
if isinstance((reaction.message.channel), discord.channel.DMChannel): #it works only in private (DM) channels
    msg = reaction.message
    channel = msg.channel
    guild = bot.get_guild(769858357607399443) #it is a valid ID of the guild with the bot
    member = guild.get_member(user.id)
    emoji_count = reaction.count
    if emoji_count > 1:
        if reaction.emoji == "":
            print("test")
        elif reaction.emoji == "":
            await channel.send("Enter the person's nickname.")
            def check(m):
                return m.author.id == user.id
            answer = await bot.wait_for("message", check = check)
from there  for memb in guild.members:
                print(memb.nick)
                if memb.nick.lower() == answer.content.lower():
to there        member_act = memb
            cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE discord_user_id = 
            {member_act.id};")
            data_tuple = cur.fetchall()
            data = data_tuple[0]
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Name:", description=f" 
            {member_act.name}", color=0x0037f3)
            embed.set_author(name="PG Official Profile Card")
            embed.add_field(name = "nice")... 
            ... #just the rest of embed.
            await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

When I tested it there were 3 people online: me (not the owner), the bot, and the test account, and 3 people offline.
The bot does not see members except my account, so prints only one nickname and then shows the error.

```
Tony_Forlatt ### it is the nickname of my account
None ### the reason of the error
Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\plays\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", 
line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\plays\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Python\bot2.py", line 227, in on_reaction_add
if memb.nick.lower() == answer.content.lower():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Today (one day after) the bot does not print even my account name, only one `None` and then the error. Why does that happen, how to fix it?

Comment: Post more code pls

Comment: you need to enable intents.members, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935181/enable-intents-for-discord-py-bot/65935226#65935226)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I did it, but it did not help. Btw version is 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `memb.nick.lower()`, put `str(memb.nick).lower()`