# Discord DMs using bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So today I was tried to learn about python discord.py .

At some point I tried the following thing:
A person tells a bot a command (`$DM 'discord user' 'content'`) and through all the research I had done, I could only find `client.author.send("message")` where `client = discord.Client()`.

Is there any way to do something like:

```
user = 'example#0000'
client.user.send("message")
```

?

Comment: You're gonna have to add your current code, there's a ton of ways to do this, I'd be a lot of help if you could provide some code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this

From user ID

```py
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx, id: int, *, content):
    user = client.get_user(id)
    await user.send(content)

# Invoking
# $DM 123123123123123 something here
```

From user name#discriminator

```py
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx, username, *, content):
    name, discriminator = username.split("#")
    user = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=name, discriminator=discriminator)
    await user.send(content)

# Invoking
# $DM example#1111 something here
```

With user mentions, ID's, names, nicknames (best option imo)

```py
@client.command()
async def DM(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, content):
    await member.send(content)

# Invoking
# $DM @example#1111 something here
# $DM 1231231231231 something here
# $DM example#1111 something here
```

Also make sure you enabled `intents.members`, for more info look at one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935181/enable-intents-for-discord-py-bot/65935226#65935226)

*PS: You need to use `commands.Bot` in order for all of this to work, not `discord.Client`*