# How to have a bot send a message to a user once reacting to a message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to figure out what I am missing in the `on_reaction_add(message)` function to have the bot send a message when a user reacts to another player's message.

```
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):
    """
    Looks for when a member calls 'bhwagon', and after 24 minutes, sends them a message
    :param message: the message sent by the user
    :return: a DM to the user letting them know their cooldown ended
    """
    if message.content.startswith("bhwagon") or message.content.startswith("missed wagon"):
        await cool_down_ended(message)
        await on_reaction_add(message)


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(message):
    """
    Checks to see if there is a reaction on a message, and if there is, then send that user a message
    :param message: represents the context in which a command is being invoked under
    :return:
    """
    if message.emoji == '882814250710626405':  # If a certain reaction is used on a message
        await message.author.send("message")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few errors/things here that don't make sense to me.

1. `on_reaction_add` has no `message` parameter, but depends on `reaction` and `user`.
2. `await message.author.send()` would always send a message to the author of the message and not to the person who reacted, that does not work.
3. Your given ID seems to be more of a message ID, but not a real emoji-ID.

Global emotes are usually built like this:
`<:NAME:ID` - This is how it has to be specified in the code too.

Emojis from Discord can be copied easily.

***IMPORTANT:*** All emojis must be preceded by `\` to get either the name or the emoji to copy.

**Based on my information now a new possible code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user): # reaction & user as an argument
    if reaction.emoji == '✅': # See if the reaction is the same as in the code
        await user.send("message") # Send the user who reacted a message
```

**!!** Please note that you also enable intents for this. Good contributions to this: [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) & [Answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935181/enable-intents-for-discord-py-bot) **!!**